# Adding attribute to prototype function in other file

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypejs, function-prototypes, prototype-chain

I have this prototype function defined in a common.js

```
goog.ui.tree.TreeControl.prototype.enterDocument = function() {
    goog.ui.tree.TreeControl.superClass_.enterDocument.call(this);
    var a = this.getElement();
    a.setAttribute("hideFocus", "true");
};
```

I want to add attribute to this function in new.js

Expected Output:

```
goog.ui.tree.TreeControl.prototype.enterDocument = function() {
    goog.ui.tree.TreeControl.superClass_.enterDocument.call(this);
    var a = this.getElement();
    a.setAttribute("hideFocus", "true");
    a.setAttribute("aria-label","Menu")
};
```

Comment: you dont have to do anything special here, you just have to include the `common.js ` file first and then include `new.js` and it will be overriden.

are you getting any errors, when you try to do it ?

Comment: I included common.js file and in new.js I want to add only aria-label . So I tried to write this.getElement().setAttribute("label","Menu).It says  this.getElement() is not a function.

Comment: My function in **new.js** looks like this :  `oldEnterDocument = goog.ui.tree.TreeControl.prototype.enterDocument;goog.ui.tree.TreeControl.prototype.enterDocument = function(){ this.getElement().setAttribute("label","Menu"); oldEnterDocument.call(this, arguments); }`

Comment: what does your `this` refer to ?

Comment: I dont want to override new.js with the same function written in common.js as the function code is large. I just want to add attribute (a line of code) to it. I mean patch a file. Is it possible?

Comment: **this** refers to  root element **Blockly.Toolbox.TreeControl** . **this.__proto__** refers to goog.ui.tree.TreeControl

Comment: you are trying to do something like this correct? 
https://codepen.io/nijeesh4all/pen/WNNgBQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202273/discussion-between-nijeesh-joshy-and-divya).